# Finding a value in a Binary Search Tree

Tags: javascript, binary-tree

I am making the code of a function to find a value passed by parameter in a BinarySearchTree but it is not working for me and I don't know why.if the price is inside the tree I have to return true, if the price passed by parameter is less than or equal to 0 I have to return "error" and if it is not found I must return false this is my code.

```
BinarySearchTree.prototype.searchPrice = function (price) {

    if (price <= 0) return "Error"  
    
    if(this.value === price) return true;

    if(this.value < price) return this.right.searchPrice(price);

    if(this.value > price) return this.left.searchPrice(price);

    if(this.value === null) return false;
};
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**"It doesn't work" isn't descriptive** enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but **descriptive summary of your problem as the title** of your question."_

Comment: do you have a tree as well?

Comment: @Andreas the question is very clear: OP has a binary search tree, they are trying to determine if a value in the tree exists, and their search function is not giving the correct value.

Comment: @Diegohp141 at first glance your function appears correct (though I am not an expert here). Do you mind sharing your tree implementation as well?

Comment: @MatthewHerbst What's clear about the question? o.O The title consists of two words (one being a tag with a spelling error that should never be part of the title). The body of the question only mentions that _"it is not working"_ without any example (input, expected output, actual output) and no [mcve] at all.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst If its clear why did you have to edit the title (which is still not a _"descriptive summary of your problem as the title"_)?

Comment: I have a construction function BinarySearchTree that receives an argument by parameter, a value, and when building the new tree it has a value and a right in null and a left in null and then I have another function to insert new values ​​to the abrol (new sub trees) that the values ​​also receive it by parameter

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be that you have `null` check for `this.value` at the end which causes the
`if(this.value < price)`  always to be `true` when `this.value` is `null`

Try to move the line `if(this.value === null) return false;` at the top and see if it works

UPDATE:
Also you need to add `null` checks for the `this.left` and `this.right`

```
BinarySearchTree.prototype.searchPrice = function (price) {

    if (price <= 0) return "Error"  

// move this line at the top like this
    if(this.value === null) return false;
    
    if(this.value === price) return true;

    if(this.value < price) {
        if(!this.right) {
            return false;
        }
        return this.right.searchPrice(price);
    }

    if(this.value > price){
        if(!this.left) {
            return false;
        }
        return this.left.searchPrice(price);
    }

};
```

Comment: Oh, that's a good one! JavaScript at it's finest :D `null < 10 // true`. Good catch! Context for others: when `null` is converted to a number it converts to 0: `+null // 0`

Comment: hi, i try to move the line as you suggest bu the result is the same

Comment: @Diegohp141 All right. In that case, could you please provide your implementation of the BinarySearchTree and the input test case that you are using. Otherwise It's hard for us the deduct what's the issue.

I mean the code itself. I saw your comment above. But without code its not helpful

Comment: @Diegohp141 I have updated the code, maybe it solves the issue.